# UIView to parent viewcontroller access

Tags: objective-c, ios, uiview, uiviewcontroller

I am not able to access UIView parent view reference or objects. In my example I have two UIWebview and UIView. From UIView i have to control UIWebView but i am not getting any reference from UIView.

Any assists on this?

-Murali

Comment: Are they all located within one viewController.m? If yes, assign those views to IVARs and create a custom method.

Comment: The array for the `subviews` property will contain the `UIWebView`s if I understand the question correctly. You need to explain how you're creating the views (NIB or code?) and how you're trying to access the individual views, what you're expecting and what is happening instead.

Comment: Yes i have loaded it in viewcontroller.m only, i have placed one UIView and adding subview to the uiview.                          cc=[[customcomp alloc] init];
[myView addSubview:cc.view];